# How to use command zip in linux that folder have short path?

Tags: linux, zip, compression, redhat

I used command zip in linux (RedHat), this is my command:

```
zip -r /home/username/folder/compress/zip.zip /home/username/folder/compressed/*
```

Then, i open file zip.zip, i see architecture as path folder compress.

I want to in folder zip only consist list file *.txt

Because i used this command in script crontab hence i can't use command cd to path folder before run command zip

Please help me

Comment: Can you just `cd` to the directory and then `cd` back?

Comment: no, i run command zip at folder /home and don't use command cd, i want run command zip not use command cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skimmed the zip man page and this is what I have found. There is not an option archive files relative to a different directory. The closest I have found is `zip -j` which removes the entire path and stores the files directly in the zip rather than sub directories. I do not know what happens in the case of file name conflicts such as if `/home/username/folder/compressed/a.txt` and `/home/username/folder/compressed/subdir/a.txt` both exist. If this is not a problem for you, you can use this option, but I am concerned because you did specify the `-r` option indicating that you expect zip to traverse sub folders.

I also thought of the possibility that your script could somehow call zip with a different working directory, but I took a look at this [unix stack exchange page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13802/execute-a-specific-command-in-a-given-directory-without-cding-to-it) and it looks like their options use `cd`.

I have to admit I do not understand why you cannot use `cd` and I am very curious about it. You said something about using crontab, but I have never heard of anything wrong with changing directories in a crontab script.

Answer (score 0):

I used option -j in command zip

```
zip -jr /home/username/folder/compress/zip.zip /home/username/folder/compressed/*
```

and i was yet settled this problem, thanks